# Error de conexión a SQL Server usando PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Intento conectarme a una base de datos SQL Server pero me sale el siguiente error:

> [image: Aunque en el texto no se ve, pego una imagen que muestra un pequeño caracter entre las palabras ´option´ y ´was´ y me pregunto si es esto lo que afecta la conexión].

Pego la imagen para que noten un pequeño caracter entre las palabras ´option´ y ´was´ y me pregunto si es esto lo que afecta la conexión.

Debajo están los dos archivos que estoy usando.

Los datos de la conexión los he validado, pero el error permanece.

Gracias por la ayuda.

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

// Definir las variables de conexión
$servername = "http://www.*******.***\******";
$databasename = "*****";
$username = "******";
$password = "********";

// Conectarse a la base de datos

function conectar_sql() {
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, array(
    "Database" => $databasename,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password,
  ));

  // Comprobar la conexión
  if ($conn === false) {
    die("Error de conexión: " . sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message']);
  }

  return $conn;
}

// Cerrar la conexión
function desconectar_sql($conn) {
  sqlsrv_close($conn);
}

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php

// Incluir las bibliotecas necesarias
require_once 'conexion.php';
require_once 'csv.php';

// Conectarse a la base de datos
$con = conectar_sql(); 

// Obtener el nombre de la vista
$vista = "dbo.*****";

...

...
?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pones `http://` en `$servername`?

Comment: Es sin http, allí necesitas un dominio y no una url

Comment: ¿La base de dato a están en un servidor distinto del que hace la conexión?

Comment: Sí, está en otro servidor. @A.Cedano,

Comment: En ese caso, en el `$servername` deberías poner la dirección IP del servidor remoto y quizá el puerto en que está corriendo SQL Server en ese servidor, en caso de que no sea el puerto por defecto. [Revisa la doc al respecto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/logging-in-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Debes escribir los datos de conexión según la configuración de ese SQL Server. Puede que también sea necesario que dicho servidor acepte las conexiones remotas, para más seguridad al respecto conviene autorizar por IP o por rangos de IP.